# Implementation API for mobile APP

Tags: rest, symfony

I am programming a Symfony2 App. The structure of my Symfony2 app like:

- Login (username / password)
- Get Survey for this Login / for this User
- User input / click answers. After each click a Ajax request save the answer
- User submit survey after answering every question

I have no experience with mobile apps like IOS, Android or Windows. The mobile will created by an other team. The question ist quite common, but which steps i must realize? Are there any literature that you can recommend me?

What was the right way to create an API?

How far Symfony2 supports to create an API for this use cases?

Unfortunately I have no experience on REST, but i suspect this is necessary, right?

I look forward to each answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me state the obvious first, if you start building a project with technologies you don't know enough about, it WILL be a nightmare. So by all means take your time to learn what you need.

REST is the reccomended standard to build an API since it's native http native and it's quite simple and flexible at the same time. There are tons of simple tutorials on REST, starting from Wikipedia, so I won't link them here.

But I'll tell you a secret, a web service can simply be any web page that reply to your requests with structured data. I.e. even a non-REST series of "webpages" the reply with JSON data can be defined a web service.

By now you see that you can easily do that with Symfony. If you already know how to do stuff and show pages with Symfony, only add [JSONResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response) to the mix , and also the [_format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#book-routing-format-param) routing parameter, and you should be on a good way.

You just create a path (i.e. an action) for whatever the mobile application needs to do. Of course later on you will learn the beauty of REST and refactor your API accordingly, but first thing you build a working system.

Comment: many thanks for this information. First i will try the simpley way with JSON Responsive an later the beauty way with REST :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading this [blog post is a good start](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/). Now if your application will only serve API responses there is the very good [Symfony REST Edition](https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition) which already includes all bundles and tools needed to create an API centric application with Symfony2.

You also have the [Lionframe framework](https://github.com/Lakion/Lionframe) but I didn't tested it yet.

Comment: thank you a lot for this informations, i will read the blog post and look into Symfony REST Edition